# How to swap "index.php?" with "index.php@" in URL strings via htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a static copy of my original dynamic site. The original site had urls something like this:

http://www.example.com/index.php?module=prodreviews&func=showcontent&id=728

However, since I now have a static copy of my site, all the urls have @ instead of ? and an .htm extension.

So current url format: http://www.example.com/index.php@module=prodreviews&func=showcontent&id=728.htm

What are the mod_rewrite rules that will redirect any requests for the old URL structure (the "?" in the url and no .htm extension) to the new URL format? I'd basically like to enable anyone that comes to my site via an old link will be taken to the right page, even though the URL format has changed.

I've been playing around with writing some rules, but no dice.

Here's what I have so far, but this only adds a .htm extension on any URL automatically. I still need to replace any URL requests that have a "?" after the "php" with "@":

```
Options +FollowSymlinks Options +Indexes RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
# add .html file extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.htm [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the query string as part of your rewrite rule's target:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}@%{QUERY_STRING}\.htm -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1@%1.htm? [L]
```

Comment: been testing it -- it does work for most cases. But one addition: for some of the queries, I need to ignore the capital letters which seems to mess up the link structure somewhat. For example, if this is a URL link someone follows to go to a site on my page, how would I do ignore the capital letter in the query? So this  http://www.mytestcom/modules.php?op=modload&name=Sections&File=index&req=listarticles&secid=4 would need to become http://www.mytest.com/modules.php@op=modload&name=sections&file=index&req=listarticles&secid=4.htm

Comment: In order to convert to lowercase, you need to have access to your server's config or vhost config and use a `RewriteMap`, see: http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/